# Bubble sort algorithm | 'str' object does not support item assignment - Python

Tags: python, typeerror, bubble-sort

**The brief:** I challenged myself to write a program, as asked in a textbook, to test my understanding and demonstrate proficiency in the 'bubble sort'. The problem asked to write a program that *"allows the user to enter 20 names into a String array. Sort the array in ascending (alphabetical) order and display its contents."* My initial code worked, however I wasn't satisfied and one unsuccessful attempted code change later, I am stumped for a viable solution.

**The issue:** I initially wrote the `friendInput` function with for a loop, that iterates 20 times (`for listInput in range(20):`), to allow for 20 individual inputs, respective to the 20 values for the user to input. Whilst this worked, I consider it quite tedious from a user perspective, especially with a range of 20, to have to keep typing, hitting return, then repeating for 20 values.

**Original code:**

```
def friendInput():                                               
    friendList  = []                                             
    for listInput in range(20):                                  
        friendList.append(input("Please enter a friends name: "))      
    print("You added these to the list: "+' | '.join(friendList))
    return friendList
```

**Attempted code re-write:**

```
def friendInput():
    friendList = []
    separator = ","
    friendList = input("Please enter friend's names, separated with commas: ")
    print("You added these to the list:",friendList.split(separator))
    return friendList
```

I did some research and learnt a lot, including the `.split()` function and tried to implement this, unsuccessfully it appears.
**Bubble sort algorithm:**

```
def bubbleSort(friendList):
    for friends in range (0, len(friendList) - 1):
        for x in range (0, len(friendList) - 1 - friends):
            if friendList[x] > friendList[x+1]:
                friendList[x], friendList[x+1] = friendList[x+1],  friendList[x]
    return friendList
```

**Error message:**
Everything seemed logical in my head, until the debugger threw back a `TypeError:` 'str' object does not support item assignment. The  `TypeError:` goes on to quote part of my `bubbleSort` function - `friendList[x], friendList[x+1] = friendList[x+1], friendList[x]`

**Where I need help:**
I suppose the error is really just saying that I'm trying to access and change a string, which is obviously disallowed, as it's not immutible. I am struggling to find a code change that would look clear, concise and not burden the user.

Can someone kindly offer suggestions, to remedy this error?

Comment: In your input function use `friendList = friendList.split(separator)`, you're trying to do assignments on parts of a string which doesn't work. Right now you're just returning the string rather than the list of strings (note this is referring to your rewrite)

Comment: Blazing quick response and very much appreciated. Would it be fair to say I was close's to the solution :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is python string split() not splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238517/why-is-python-string-split-not-splitting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-read these lines:

```
friendList = input("Please enter friend's names, separated with commas: ")
print("You added these to the list:",friendList.split(separator))
return friendList
```

You are creating a string `friendList = input`... and then you are returning the string (`return friendList`). You intend to create a list and then return the list.

Try this instead:

```
friendList = input("Please enter friend's names, separated with commas: ")
friendList = friendList.split(separator)
print("You added these to the list:",friendList)
return friendList
```